# C# string literal GetHashCode() evaluates differently given context?

Tags: c#, hashcode

So I have some code that is failing because two string literals have HashCodes that can evaluate to the same thing.  And while I appreciate that collision can happen I wasn't quite expecting this.  But whilst debugging an issue in code a colleague and I found that in an immediate window if we did

```
"55d02ProductAd".GetHashCode() == "55b0tProductAd".GetHashCode()
```

It would evalute to `true`.  Not ideal, but not impossible.  When we described this to another colleague, in his disbelief he wrote up a scratch program that did

```
var h1 = "55d02ProductAd".GetHashCode();
var h2 = "55b0tProductAd".GetHashCode();
Console.WriteLine(h1 == h2);
```

In the above, they do not evaluate to the same thing.  We have our monitors next to each other and we are confused as to the different outputs.  Any thoughts?

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode(v=vs.110).aspx `You should never persist or use a hash code outside the application domain in which it was created, because the same object may hash across application domains, processes, and platforms.`

Comment: they do have the same hash code at least in .net 4.5 https://dotnetfiddle.net/O3VUtX

Comment: 1. Do both on the same machine - different machines may produce different hashes. 2. The both equate to true on my machine.3. Dont ever use hash codes for equality. Hash codes are not unique.

Comment: @rick Even on the same machines it's *allowed* to produce different hashes.

Comment: Related: http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/string.cs,838

Comment: @Servy you are absolutely right - i should have stated on the same machine and the same console app instance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hash codes are only contractually obligated to produce the same hash for a value within the context of a single application's execution.  Since you're comparing the values of `GetHashCode` form entirely different applications, there is no obligation for them to be equal.

Comment: He is not saying that he is comparing values from different applications. He says that one application produces different values.

Comment: @Stilgar No, he's not.  He's saying he had an application, computed these hashes, then a coworker created a new application, hashed the same strings, and got different values.  That's an entirely different application.  And of course, even if it was the same application, if it was a different invocation of it, the hash would be allowed to vary.  If you just print the hash of "Hello World!" and run it over and over it's *allowed* to give a different value.

Comment: Also, the [birthday problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Birthday_problem) makes collisions reasonably common. Many structures that rely on hash codes (like `Dictionary<TK, TV>`) handle collisions elegantly.

Comment: @Haney Well, any that don't are buggy.  *Every* sensible implementation needs to handle collisions.

Comment: @Haney sensible handling is not using hashes to determine equality - but rather inequality. It's really an easy way to exclude things from matching algorithms, within the same application domain.